# Issue with creating Admin account in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have selected Jenkins Own User Database Option and unchecked Allow users to sign up option.
Selected Legacy Mode Autherization.

In the signup page, I have given all the details username, Password, name , email. After clicking on sign up I got the below Error.

```
Status Code: 500
Exception: Bad version number in .class file
Stacktrace: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Bad version number in .class file
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:615)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:658)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:203)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:573)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:658)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:487)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    at hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm$5.doFilter(HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.java:694)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:98)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:64)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Generated by Stapler at Mon Feb 25 01:29:25 CST 2013
```

Now I am not able to login into Jenkins.

Please help me in creating the Admin Account.

Comment: Which java version are you using? Did you recently switch to a newer version or trying to use classes compiled in later version on an old setup?

Comment: I am using JDK6. and the jenkins is deployed on tomcat 5.5.25

Comment: This looks like a conflicting java version issue. Are you running Tomcat with this JDK? Can you make sure you don't have an older JDK running Tomcat?

Comment: Thanks Shiva Kumar and Eldad AK. I was using JDK5. Now it is working after pointing to JDK6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was Using JDK5. After pointing Tomcat to JDK6 issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Kishore Tamire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001311/kishore-tamire) himself, Tomcat was set to use JDK5 instead of JDK6.